# Hexadecimal to binary converter needs specific output java

Tags: java

Hi I'm new here I would like to ask question about my code:

I'm doing a hexadecimal to binary converter

Example the user inputs: `200C`:
The ouput should be:

```
2- 0011
0- 0000
0- 0000
C- 1100
```

the problem is my program just shows `0011 0000 0000 11000`

I need to show the value that the user input in my output

this is my code:

```
package javatutorials;


import java.util.Scanner;  

public class arrays  
{  
public static void main(String[]args)  
{  
 String[]hex={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};  
 String[]binary={"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};  

 Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);  
 System.out.print("Input your Hex Number here : ");  
 String userInput=s.next();  
 String result="";  
 for(int i=0;i<userInput.length();i++)  
 {  
  char temp=userInput.charAt(i);  
  String temp2=""+temp+"";  
  for(int j=0;j<hex.length;j++)
  {  
   if(temp2.equalsIgnoreCase(hex[j]))  
   {  
    result=result+"\n"+binary[j];  
   }  
  }  
 }  
 System.out.println("IT'S BINARY IS : "+result);  
}  
}
```

Comment: Just one note: if you want to concatenate multiple strings like you do with `result=result+"\n"+binary[j];`, you should use a `StringBuilder`. Otherwise you create a new String each time the statement is executed, which reduces performance.

Comment: BTW - 0011 is not 2 it is 3.

Comment: Have you Googled "Java hex to binary converter"?

Answer (score 0):

you do not add your `temp` string to the `result` therefore it is not shown. try to use

`result = result + "\n" + temp + "- " + binary[j];`

instead.

**EDIT:** using `temp` directly adds the `char` itself to the `result`. If you want to use the `temp2` String, use that instead.